# Data Comparison in 2 csv files

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have 3 files:

In `file1` I've data like this:

```
id,name,age
1,jj,60
2,kk,45
3,ss,56
```

In `file2` I've data like this:

```
id,name,age
1,jj,60
2,kk,44
3,ss,55
4,tt,66
```

In `file3` I've only one field i.e. id:

```
id
1
2
3
```

Now I want to compare `file1` & `file2` for those ID which are in `file3`.

Output should be like this:

```
id  file1   file2
2   age=45  age=44
3   age=56  age=55
```

Comment: Why is `id` 1 missing?

Comment: Because id 1 having same values for all fields in both files. Only id 2 & 3 having differences which i need to capture from file1 & file2

Comment: Differ in column3 or in whole line?

Comment: File1 & File2 having more than 50 columns and difference may be in any of those column except ID column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended **`paste`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -F',' -v ids=$(paste -s -d'|' <(tail -n+2 file3)) \
'BEGIN{ OFS="\t"; print "id", ARGV[1], ARGV[2] }
 FNR==1{ next }
 NR==FNR{ if ($1 ~ "^("ids")$") a[$1$2]=$3; next }
 ($1$2 in a) && a[$1$2] != $3{ 
     printf "%d\tage=%d\tage=%d\n", $1, a[$1$2], $3 
 }' file1 file2
```

The output:

```
id  file1   file2
2   age=45  age=44
3   age=56  age=55
```

Comment: But when i am adding more columns to file1 & file2, output remain same, Its not checking other columns. My file1 & File2 having more than 50 columns.

Comment: @Anand, that does not relate to your initial question with given input files. Consider creating another question with clean description

Comment: Thanks Roman, created new question with clear details. Apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Roman's answer is good and gives you the exact output you asked for.

If, however, you **only** needed the raw data (i.e. without CSV headers and without the printf pretty-printed formatting), you could use `paste` + `comm` + `grep` + [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution):

```
$ paste <(comm -1 -3 file1 file2) <(comm -2 -3 file1 file2) | 
    grep -f <(sed -e 's/^/^/; s/$/,/;' file3)
2,kk,44 2,kk,45
3,ss,55 3,ss,56
```

Explanation:

`comm -1 -3 file1 file2` outputs the lines that are unique to `file2`.  `comm -2 -3 file1 file2` outputs the lines unique to `file1`.  The output of both these commands are given to `paste` via process substitution, and joined together.

`paste`'s output is then piped into grep to output only the lines that match the ids listed in `file3`.  Process substitution is also used here to transform the IDs listed in file3 into anchored regular expressions that match the ID numbers ONLY when they are at the start of a line and followed by a comma.

Doing something like this would mostly be useful if you wanted/needed to do further processing **before** pretty-printing the output.

Comment: (posted mostly because I'd almost finished writing this answer before I noticed the pretty-printed output requirement and didn't want to throw it away - someone with a similar question - or perhaps even the OP - might find this alternative approach useful)