# Data Comparison in 2 csv files columnwise, Input from 3rd file

Tags: awk, scripting, csv

I have 3 files:

In file1 I've data like this

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

In file2 I've data like this

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,2,3,4,5,5,7
7,6,6,4,3,2,1
```

In file3 I've only one field i.e A:

```
A
1
2
7
```

Now I want to compare file 1 & file2 on column  A which is available in file3.

Columns header & number of columns will be same in both files.

Desired output

```
Item  FILE1   FILE2
1     F=6     F=5
7     C=5     C=6
```

If there are more columns mismatch

```
   A,B,C,D,E,F,G
   1,2,3,4,5,5,7
   7,6,5,2,3,2,1

   A,B,C,D,E,F,G
   1,2,3,1,4,6,7
   7,6,6,4,3,2,1
```

Then output should like this

```
Item    FILE1   FILE2
1       D=4     D=1
        E=5     E=4
        F=5     F=6
7       C=5     C=6
        D=2     D=4
```

This is sample, Number of column may vary but it always same in both file1 & file2. And due to this its different from previous question.

Comment: Related (an expansion of): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423540/data-comparison-in-2-csv-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data Comparison in 2 csv files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423540/data-comparison-in-2-csv-files)

Comment: No, Data Comparison in 2 csv files: comparing data on fixed column but i need to compare on all columns irrespective of no. of columns

Comment: Kindly post correct example with desired output

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

join -t, file_1 file_2 | join -t, - file_3 |
awk -F, '
NR == 1 {
    fields_num = (NF + 1) / 2

    for(i = 1; i <= fields_num; i++)
        field_names[i] = $i
}
NR != 1 {
    item = $1 "\t"

    for(i = 2; i <= fields_num; i++) {
        cmp_num = i + fields_num - 1

        if($i != $cmp_num) {
            printf "%s%s=%s\t%s=%s\n",
                    item,
                    field_names[i], $i,
                    field_names[i], $cmp_num

            item = "\t"
        }

    }
}'
```

Few assumptions were made:

1. The column for comparing always the first.
2. All files sorted by the first column (`A` field).
3. Only those items, that occurs in both files (`file_1` and`file_2`) are compared. So, if the `file_1` has the item `2`, but the `file_2` hasn't, this line excluded from the comparing.

**Input**

```
tail -n +1 -- file_*

==> file_1 <==
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,2,3,4,5,5,7
7,6,5,2,3,2,1

==> file_2 <==
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,2,3,1,4,6,7
7,6,6,4,3,2,1

==> file_3 <==
A
1
2
7
```

**Output**

```
1   D=4 D=1
    E=5 E=4
    F=5 F=6
7   C=5 C=6
    D=2 D=4
```